# How do I export collection of books to csv in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am having a collection named "results" taken from an aggregate and it contains data as follows:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$numberLong": "123"
    },
    "books": [{
        "DisplayName": "ABC",
        "transaction": "20"
        }
        {
        "DisplayName": "ABC",
        "transaction": "25"
        }
        .....]

     "_id": {
        "$numberLong": "124"
    },
    "books": [{
        "DisplayName": "BCE",
        "transaction": "100"
     }
    ....]
}
```

Is there any possible way where I can convert that into a csv of this form?

```
_id  | DisplayName | Transaction
123      ABC          20
123      ABC          25
124      BCE          100
```

I tried the following code:

```
mongoexport --db dbname --collection results --out D:/mongolearn/results.csv
```

But the output csv file I get is something like this:

```
"_id": { "$numberLong": "123} | {"books": [{"DisplayName": "ABC","transaction": "20"}{ "DisplayName": "ABC" | "transaction": "25"|
```

I am a beginner to MongoDB and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Explore mongo export.

Comment: Thank you, but I have been trying for a while and I am very new to MongoDB. I will update the question to show what I have been trying and what is going wrong

Comment: You need to mention fields also. Try that.

Comment: You need to `$unwind` those nested arrays. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 0):

Mongo has a built in terminal method called [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/), The problem is you can't use aggregate with it as it is intended for more basic data export with a query filter rather than full aggregation and data processing.

You can work around this like so:

1. Create a new temporary collection using your pipeline and [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

```
db.results.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$books"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            DisplayName: "$books.DisplayName",
            Transaction: "$books.transaction"
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "temp_collection"
    }
])
```

2. In your terminal use `mongoexport like so:

```
mongoexport -d dbname -c temp_collection -f _id,DisplayName,Transaction --csv > results.csv
```

Obviously this is also achieve-able through code where you won't have to create a place holder collection as long as you can hold your entire collection in memory.